# Sympy two variables, one known, one unknown, use subs, returns no answers

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

New to sympy here, and I really can't see what I am doing wrong. I am solving for triangle area, with known height but requirement is to define two symbols.

```
def solve_math_problem():

from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve
from fractions import Fraction

base, height = symbols('base, height')
eq1 = Eq(Fraction(1, 2) * base * height, 24)
eq2 = eq1.subs(height, 8)
result = solve([eq1, eq2], base)
print(result)
```

This results in an empty array every time. When I print **eq2** I get **Eq(4*base, 24)**, how is that not enough information to solve for **base**?

I'm not sure what information I'm missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking to solve two equations for one unknown:

```
In [18]: eq1
Out[18]: 
base⋅height     
─────────── = 24
     2          

In [19]: eq2
Out[19]: 4⋅base = 24

In [20]: solve([eq1, eq2], base)
Out[20]: []
```

The `solve` function considers this to be a system of two equations with one unknown (base) and one symbolic parameter (height). This is an over-determined system of equations and may not have any solutions. In particular a solution for `base` to both equations exists only if `height` is equal to `8` but you have not told `solve` that the height is equal to `8` and it will not presume that. Instead `solve` returns the empty list because for almost all possible values of `height` this system of equations has no solution.

You can fix this in a number of ways e.g. just solve one equation for one unknown:

```
    In [21]: solve([eq2], base)
    Out[21]: {base: 6}
```

You can also solve two equations for two unknowns by treating height as an unknown as well:

```
    In [24]: solve([eq1, eq2], [base, height], dict=True)
    Out[24]: [{base: 6, height: 8}]
```